# Add 2 boxes below carousel

Tags: html, css, carousel

I am still trying to sort the size of top menu on "page2";
however I need this work to soon, and wonder if the other way will be to add a couple of boxes, like 2 containers to give ample space for the menu to work as it is designed to and get smaller.
Here is the URL as there are loads of codes: http://www.dijon-egg.com/Possum/

Thanks a lot,

Byron

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to add one or two boxes below the carousel on page2?